# Why does the favicon sometimes not show up and generate "page not found" errors, and other times does show up

Tags: 7, files

As the question implies, on occasion Drupal's log is showing that the favicon is not found. Indeed, it does not show in the browser tab or address bar. At other times, even within the same surfing session, it does show up.

Why does it do this and how can I prevent it so that the favicon will always show?

I am using version Drupal 7.22. with a custom subtheme and an admin theme (Stark).

My favicon is set in the subtheme theme configuration at sites/default/files/images/favicon.ico and that is located there as I have checked via FTP.

The log shows the browser is looking in example.com/favicon.ico.

The custom subtheme I use has `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/sites/default/files/images/favicon.ico"; type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />` in the source code and the admin theme (Stark) uses `<link type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://example.com/misc/favicon.ico"; rel="shortcut icon">` and this file also exists in that location (not actually using example.com, of course).

Drupal is using clean URLs.

The web server is Apache on Debian Linux.

Thank you.

Comment: Might help if you would provide referer for these errors, should be in log.

Comment: @Molot The referrer field is either blank or another page in the site in all cases I have checked in the log.

Comment: Can you edit in the log message to show the path, what webserver you are using, as well as whether mod_rewrite works (ie, clean URLs)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some browsers search for favicon under http://example.com/favicon.ico without checking. But they are minority now.

Most respect:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://example.com/img/icon.png">
```

as [described by W3C](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon).

If your site tries to use `<link>` approach but fails on some pages, like admin pages rendered using different template, and you do not have favicon.ico in default location, you will get exactly described effects.

If browser is looking for  http://example.com/favicon.ico when you have proper `<link rel="shortcut icon">` it is a browser problem, not yours. It means browser (or at least that part of it's code) is outdated, unless it looked under correct URI first and got another error, but then you would see two errors in log, one for right place, second for outdated one. In Mozilla's queue there is a number of reports about improper favicon detection by FireFox - in example [this one](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=855910). It shows how even modern browsers can sometimes fall back to old methods.

Comment: Yes the log shows the browser is looking in http://example.com/favicon.ico. The custom subtheme I use for the site does give <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/images/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" /> in the source code (not actually example.com) which is the correct location. If I turn off the overlay, the admin theme is using <link type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://www.example.com/misc/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"> and this file also exists in that location.

Comment: Everything seems correct as it should be. So is this a browser problem or website problem? Where would I go to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: @authentictech if browser is looking for  example.com/favicon.ico when you have proper `<link rel="shortcut icon">` it is a browser problem, not yours. It means browser is outdated, unless it looked under correct place first and got another error, but then you would see it in logs just before this one. I'll update my question.

Comment: Actually, the last paragraph here isn't totally accurate.  The default .htaccess with Drupal 7 has a rule to prevent Drupal from handling the /favicon.ico path (it's line 112 in 7.22).  Something odd is happening here.

Comment: @MPD It might not be served by Apache; Pantheon's nginx config omits that rule for example (if I remember rightly)

Comment: @Mołot If we are talking about the same line, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico` prevents Drupal from handling that path, so the user gets a "fast" 404.  I don't get a Drupal 404 on any site I have tested this on.

Comment: @MPD oh, my mistake, my Drupal has it "hacked". Either way, browser should not look there at all if it's defined properly as a `<link>`.

Comment: @Mołot I always use the latest Firefox browser (currently 22) and I know that the "favicon not found" log shows when it is me connecting to the site. Perhaps that part of your answer is wrong?

Comment: @authentictech Firefox has numerous open bug reports about improper favicon handling. Like [this one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=855910) for example. Parts of it's code are old, sad but true. If you want to handle that, you can add rewrite to your .htaccess, but it *will* be hacking around a browser bug, not fixing site bug.

Comment: @Mołot, yes that seems to be the explanation then. Do you want to add a little bit about the Firefox bug to your answer? Then I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and easy fix for this pain, is to use the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module and make a redirect for it.

Once the module is enabled, go to `admin/config/search/redirect/add` and use `favicon.ico` under from and to should be the actual location of your theme's `favicon.ico`.

Comment: This file is automatically handled by .htaccess so the request never makes it to Drupal for the Redirect module to handle it.

Comment: Yes it does make it to Drupal. Otherwise how would it be logged in the Drupal log? I have used this approach successfully in production.

Comment: You are right, i just tested this. Edited your original answer so that I can switch my downvote to an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache, the best way I found to fix it is to put:

```
<Location /favicon.ico>
  ErrorDocument 404 "No favicon"
</Location>
```

This code should work in your vhost file or should also work in the .htaccess file, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html for more details

Answer (score -1):

You can try https://www.drupal.org/project/favicon
It to make requests to http://example.com/favicon.ico forward to the actual site's true favicon.